# How to insert DataGridRow directly in database?

Tags: c#, wpf, t-sql

I have 2 data grids and one combobox on one tab in my WPF app.

The first data grid contains data from different tables, which are chosen from a combo box. When I select a row in that data grid, that row is displayed in the second data grid.

I want to change the values in that row, in the second data grid, and then directly update the table that contains that data.

How can I do that? Is there any way to directly insert a `DataGridRow` into that table?

Comment: What do you have already? This will help us see how you are planning on saving the data i.e. Save button.

Answer (score 0):

are you storing the datagridview row values in a dataset?
if so , you can pass this dataset to a stored procedure to insert into a database table

check this to know how to pass dataset to a stored procedure.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S